# Who are all of these characters/vessels in this next generation era image?

Tags: star-trek, character-identification, object-identification

I was recently sent an image by a friend containing many different Star Trek characters and vessels from the next generation era.

Several of the main characters are pretty obvious, with the TNG crew in the bottom third. Several of vessels are pretty clear too with DS9, Enterprise-D, Stargazer and Enterprise-C (on the right).

[image: Next Generation Era]

Can we identify the other characters and vessels?

Comment: This question has already been asked.

Comment: Looks like the image link is broken on the original question, but easily looks to be the duplicate based on the answer key, provided by the artist,  posted in the accepted answer..

Comment: @Radhil You can also tell from some of the prior edits on the question; only the most recently-added link is dead. This is why we have imgur